# How do I remove results based on conditions to calculate an average

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have the schema below. A quick explanation of it is:

1. bob rated up 5/5
2. james rated up 1/5
3. macy rated up 5/5

The logic:

1. If I am personA, look up everyone I have blocked.
2. Look up all the movie reviews.
3. Anyone who has left a movie review, and personA has blocked, remove them from the calculation.
4. Calculate the average rating of the movies.

---

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE reviews (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  rating integer NOT NULL,
  cus_id integer NOT NULL,
  movie_id integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
);

CREATE TABLE blocked(
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  cus_id integer NOT NULL, -- This is the person blocking
  blocked_cus_id integer NOT NULL, -- This is the person who is blocked
  FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (blocked_cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
);

INSERT INTO movies (id, name) VALUES (1, 'up');
INSERT INTO customer (id, name) VALUES (1, 'bob'), (2, 'james'), (3, 'macy');
INSERT INTO reviews (id, rating, cus_id, movie_id) VALUES (1, 5, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1), (3, 5, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO blocked (id, cus_id, blocked_cus_id) VALUES (1, 1, 2);
```

I don't understand how I can get rid of reviews if its on a block list

```
SELECT m.name, avg(r.rating) as avg_rating
FROM movies m
JOIN reviews r ON m.id = r.movie_id
JOIN blocked b on r.cus_id = b.blocked_cus_id
WHERE b.cus_id = 1 -- Viewing the database as bob
```

When I view the database as bob, I should get:

```
+-------+------------+
| movie | avg_rating |
+-------+------------+
| up    |          5 |
+-------+------------+
```

When I view the database as macy, I should get:

```
+-------+------------+
| movie | avg_rating |
+-------+------------+
| up    |       3.67 |
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the `blocked` table?  Should any review which is blocked by someone else be ignored?  Or some other logic?

Comment: So if Bob blocked James. Then when Bob is finding the average score for a movie. Then any review James has put up (for any movie) is completely ignored when calculating the average for that particular movie.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Updated it. I just assumed the database was empty.

Comment: Also if Macy is viewing the database, well macy hasn't blocked anyone, so all the reviews are taken into account for that particular movie @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to express your logic without using an exists clause. I might try here:

```sql
SELECT m.name, AVG(r.rating) AS avg_rating
FROM movies m
INNER JOIN reviews r ON m.id = r.movie_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b
                  WHERE b.blocked_cus_id = r.cus_id AND b.cus_id = 1)
GROUP BY m.name;
```

Note that we want to aggregate by movie name, so we need `GROUP BY` here.  The exists clause says to *exclude* from the average rating any review for which we can find a blocked entry belonging to a certain customer (in this case, `cus_id = 1`).

Comment: I'm so sorry but what if blocked_cus_id is never null. the block list only contains people which a customer has blocked. I updated the create table sql

Comment: You want to discount/ignore a review should the customer be blocked.  My query has logic which should do that.  If you can't make it work still, then add sample data to your question, or maybe a demo link.

Comment: I've added some demo data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6563896/6
Its my schema. And the issue is that its not calculating the average correctly.

Comment: Yea its hard, so, I don't know how do it it. So if you check in jame's perspective, he hasn;t blocked anyone, so his average score should be 5 too because james hasn;t blocked anyone. But his perspective of the joker movie's average is 3.667

Comment: I think my updated answer should be working you now.  Please check.

Comment: I've updated my question to if statements and sort of broke it down into steps so its easier to understand the paragram i wrote which was the logic.

Comment: [Check this demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6563896/8) to see my answer working for Macy.

Comment: The demo is the answer