# How to show reviews based on conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have the schema below. A quick explanation of it is:

1. bob rated the movie up, 5/5
2. james rated the movie up, 1/5
3. macy rated the movie up, 5/5
4. No one has rated the movie avengers.

The logic:

1. If I am personA, look up everyone I have blocked.
2. Look up the reviews of a specific movie.
3. Anyone who has left a review on that movie and personA has blocked, remove them from the results

---

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE reviews (
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  rating integer NOT NULL,
  cus_id integer NOT NULL,
  movie_id integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
);

CREATE TABLE blocked(
  id integer AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  cus_id integer NOT NULL, -- This is the person blocking
  blocked_cus_id integer NOT NULL, -- This is the person who is blocked
  FOREIGN KEY (cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (blocked_cus_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
);

INSERT INTO movies (id, name) VALUES (1, 'up'), (2, 'avengers');
INSERT INTO customer (id, name) VALUES (1, 'bob'), (2, 'james'), (3, 'macy');
INSERT INTO reviews (id, rating, cus_id, movie_id) VALUES (1, 5, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2, 1), (3, 5, 3, 1);
INSERT INTO blocked (id, cus_id, blocked_cus_id) VALUES (1, 1, 2);
```

I am trying to get the list of reviews left for the movie id `1`. I modified the statement I got help with from here: [How do I remove results based on conditions to calculate an average and specific movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840427/how-do-i-remove-results-based-on-conditions-to-calculate-an-average-and-specific) but the issue is that it only shows 1 one review, even though there are 2-3.

```
SELECT 
  r.rating,
  c.name
FROM movies m
LEFT JOIN reviews r 
    ON m.id = r.movie_id
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM blocked b
        WHERE b.blocked_cus_id = r.cus_id AND b.cus_id = 1 -- viewing the database as bob
    )
JOIN customer c ON r.cus_id = c.id
WHERE m.id = 1
GROUP BY m.id, m.name;
```

In the above statement I only get the first review posted.

```
+--------+------+
| rating | name |
+--------+------+
|      5 | bob  |
+--------+------+
```

I want to get the result below, as this is in the perspective of bob who has blocked james, thus we don't show james's review:

```
+--------+------+
| rating | name |
+--------+------+
|      5 | bob  |
|      5 | macy |
+--------+------+
```

When I view the database as macy, I should see everyone's reviews, since macy hasn't blocked anyone:

```
+--------+-------+
| rating | name  |
+--------+-------+
|      5 | bob   |
|      1 | james |
|      5 | macy  |
+--------+-------+
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a6e71/4

Comment: Did one of these answers solve your problem? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?

Answer (score 0):

I mean below query is what you need:

```
select 
    m.id movie_id, 
    m.name movie_name, 
    r.name reviwed_by,
    r.rating
from movies m
left join (
  select movie_id, name, rating, b.cus_id blocked_by
  from reviews r
  join customer c on c.id = r.cus_id
  left join blocked b on b.cus_id = r.cus_id
)r on m.id = r.movie_id
where m.id = 1 and (r.blocked_by is null or r.blocked_by <> 1)
;
```

Result from [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=ccdfbb263069fb694199bb4ea87638d4&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57) (reviews for movie 1 for customer 1)

```
+==========+============+============+========+
| movie_id | movie_name | reviwed_by | rating |
+==========+============+============+========+
| 1        | up         | james      | 1      |
+----------+------------+------------+--------+
| 1        | up         | macy       | 5      |
+----------+------------+------------+--------+
```